# Changing a bullet style in content page of beamer

Tags: beamer

I made the agenda page using

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents %
\end{frame}
```

and would like to change the bullet style circle to default.
But any command doesn't work for me.

Do you have any idea of this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This question would be better if you included information about the theme being used.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for more advice.

Answer (score 2):

To revert back to the default layout of the table of contents, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents %
\end{frame}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want numbered section instead of the default behaviour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents %
\end{frame}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My question might be confusing. Your suggestion makes the agenda have no itemize (that is, no number). I would like to do like 1. title 2. title ..., just don't like the style of a circle number.

Comment: @Sato Numbered sections are not default in beamer

Comment: Very thank you! Your identification is very swift and precise!